# Python 3 Webcam

Tags: python, webcam

im trying to make a face detection program and I need to access my webcam. Im strictly using python 3 for this project. I have tried OpenCv and video capture, but those only work for python 2.7. Is there any way that I can code this manually in python to,

1. A.use command line to do this,
2. Manually code this in python somehow, or
3. Any other modules(that work with 3).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean another version? Python 4 doesn't exist yet...

Comment: Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 has some notable differences, but everything is different when you talk about open source libraries like OpenCV. If OpenCV implementation of Python is based on some older version (e.g. 2.7 or older), then I don't think 3.3 will work successfully. Having said that, OpenCV should have used intrinsic functionality of Python in 2.7 which would allow forward compatibility (e.g. 3.3. or 3.4). You can give it a try and if you see an extensive set of errors with missing modules and clauses, you probably have to manually code everything.

Comment: Ahhh, I meant python 3.4. Sorry. I was thinking they were different. XD Face Palm*

Comment: python 4 which planet you belongs too ?? Dr mann or millars :)

Comment: read my earlier comment. And yes i do live on Dr mann's planet. :)

Comment: I'd suggest try with the OpenCV meant for Python 2.7, maybe it'll work with Python 3.X anyway. If not interface with C++ version of OpenCV directly, e.g. using `scipy.weave` or just having an application in C++ that would do the Maths and calling it from Python using `subprocess` or something similar. After all, if the libraries you need aren't available, you have to find workarounds.

Comment: Interesting, will i need any background knowledge of C++ to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VideoCapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) has worked really well for me in the past. The sourceforge page only shows support through python 2.7, but [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#videocapture) has pre-built installers through python 3.4. Simple, lightweight, and works.

Comment: "this page" does not have an install. I tried m-win32 and m-win_amd64, both of which do not work. I have a x64. What do you suggest?